# delete specific letter in data frame using gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame like this:

```
val                  value
a_green_0            0.1
a_green_01           0.2
....
a_green_0100         0.3
b_green_45            0.1
b_green_451           0.2
...
b_green_45100         0.2
```

I would like to remove the number 1,2,3,...100 to get the output like this:

```
val                  value
a_green_0            0.1
a_green_0            0.2
....
a_green_0            0.3
b_green_45           0.1
b_green_45           0.2
...
b_green_45           0.2
```

I used gsub like this, but this did not work:

```
gsub("*green_0*", "green_0",train1)
```

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The logic is not clear in your example

Comment: `gsub("[123]", "", train$val)` perhaps? As @akrun said, make your example more clear.

Comment: Will there always be 100 of each group and are they ordered as in the example?  If so regex may not be the best solution.

Comment: How do you distinguish between two possible interpretations of `b_green_451`? Is it the first of `b_green_45` or the 51st of `b_green_4`?

Comment: @Tyler Rinker: Yes, there is 100 of each group + @ R. Schifini: b_green_451 is the first of b_green_45

Comment: @ R. Schifini: Could you please suggest alternative solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
train1$val<-gsub("green_0.+","green_0",train1$val)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: if so may want to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example showed, this should give the expected output

```
sub("_(0|[1-9]{2})\\d+", "_\\1", df1$val)
#[1] "a_green_0"  "a_green_0"  "a_green_0"  "b_green_45" "b_green_45"
#[6] "b_green_45"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(val = c("a_green_0", "a_green_01", "a_green_0100", 
"b_green_45", "b_green_451", "b_green_45100"), value = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2)), .Names = c("val", "value"), 
 class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: It did not work with sub

Comment: @user30985 What i meant is `gsub("green_0.+","green_0", df1$val)
#[1] "a_green_0"     "a_green_0"     "a_green_0"     "b_green_45"   
[5] "b_green_451"   "b_green_45100"`   Please check your input and expected output.  If this is some kind of games, I am not into it.